# Alternative way to load XML data in database with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I am searching for an alternative way to load XML data in database with SSIS.

Why alternative ? Because we have had some very bad experiences with SSIS and XML:

- SSIS not raising error when XML is not matching the XSD (unexpected fields were present in XML)
- SSIS not able to load basic XML because the structure didn't suit him (we have finished by editing the XML on the fly to change the structure)
- low performance
- (very) cumbersome development with complex XML with parent-child nodes
- when looping on several XML, SSIS skips some of them, without raising any error, it's like if they were invisible. If you run again the treatment, it works.

So I would like to avoid these issues by using an alternative way to load XML with SSIS.
Why still using SSIS ? Because it has some benefits anyway:

- centralized management and monitoring
- specific audit flow, allowing to follow loading of XML, Txt files, tables, etc.
- developers skilled on SSIS

So I am searching how to do something close to:

- Loop on a folder where are several XML -> SSIS component
- For each XML, Insert a value in audit table marking it as "in treatment"
- Validate XML with XSD and raise error if mismatch -> ?
- If error, move the XML in a reject folder or flag the XML in audit table as "error" -> ?
- If no error, Parse XML as a DOM (or equivalent) -> ?
- Insert in database tables the content of XML, by keeping the link between parent and child node. So it means I need to be able to retrieve on the fly some sequences from SQLServer database -> ?
- Update the audit table to set the XML as "Loaded" -> ?
- Move the XML in another folder

Without SSIS in the equation, I would use java program or python but I would like to keep SSIS at least as a container.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could use SSIS as a container for a script task that does what you want in C# or vb.net.

Comment: I think you asked this before. What i do is i transform the xml in flat file using c# then i import it using ssis pack

Comment: Thanks, that's 1 of my solution indeed. My issue is that if I transform XML in CSV I will lose the parent-child relationshipt between nodes, so it's not possible.

Regarding the script in C# or vb.net, I fear that I will lose all benefits of SSIS, like mutualized connections.

I wonder if it's possible, and a good idea, to do it with T-SQL?